# How can I determine if a servo motor is in the commanded position?

Tags: servo

Once I have set PWM to move a servo to a particular angle, is there a way to detect that the servo has finished moving?  I am concerned about situations where the servo is encountering extra resistance and is struggling to reach the desired angle.

Why I need this: I want to prevent certain events from happening until the servo reaches the right angle. I also want to be able to time the servo out and report a failure if it doesn't finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the Analog Feedback Servos.

Here is a resource : [About Servos and Feedback](http://learn.adafruit.com/analog-feedback-servos/about-servos-and-feedback)

And if you want to modify a classical servo and get the feedback from it, here's an article about [how to hack a classical one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Servo-Feedback-Hack-free/). The hack is really easy to realize and your understanding of servos will be better (as all good hacks).

Basically, an analog feedback servos (buy as-is or hacked) will allow you to read from the servo the current position.

Comment: Why isn't this a standard feature of servos? I would expect feedback to be a common requirement. Do any suppliers other than Adafruit sell servos with feedback?